# Make a rails model interpret a value that isn't a column in the table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I use a series of named scopes on a model to generate a query.In that query there's a join with another table in which I have some boolean fields.
When I access the values of those columns it returns strings("0" and "1").

Is there a DRY way to tell the model how to interpret those columns?(I know i can write methods to override the accesor, but that doesn't feel right).

I'm using rails 2.3.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *"override the accessor"* you meant `read_attribute` and `write_attribute` methods, then this is absolutely the correct way to do this. Rails type casts fields automatically and AFAIK there is no direct way to influence type casting, only overriding *setters/getters*.

For integrity's sake, an example:

```
def admin_user
  read_attribute(:admin_user) == "1" ? true : false
end

def admin_user(v)
  write_attribute(v ? "1" : "0")
end
```

Note: for more complex cases (say password encryption) the best way would be [ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks). Take a look at the examples there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I eventually ended up doing it like this.I was hoping there's a way to hint to the model that a column should be interpreted as a boolean.